# Sort data which is displayed in a HTML tabled echoed in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still learning PHP & MySQL and the following has confused me for a long time and I'm looking for some guidance as to how I'd be able to do this.

Basically, I have a HTML table which is displayed by an echo which grabs the values from a MySQL database, the table displays Position, User, Today. Weekly & Monthly. The rows that the table displays is dependent on how many users are logged in so if 10 people are logged in, 10 rows will be displayed, 5 users = 5 rows etc. To achieve this I created a loop which displays the information for each logged in user and this is where I think the issue starts with sorting the data. This is what is used to display the data:

```
<?php 
            $counter = 1;
            include_once 'config.php';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM vicidial_live_agents";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $dateNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $dateNow = strtotime($dateNow);
                $dateOld = $row['last_state_change'];
                $dateOld = strtotime($dateOld);
                $dateDiff = $dateNow - $dateOld;
                if ($row['status'] == "INCALL") {
                    $colour = "w3-green";
                }
                elseif ($row['status'] == "READY") {
                    $colour = "w3-yellow";
                }   
                elseif ($row['status'] == "PAUSED") {
                    $colour = "w3-grey";
                }
                elseif ($row['status'] == "DEAD") {
                    $colour = "w3-red";
                }
                $user = $row['user'];
                echo 
                '<tr class="'.$colour.'">
                <td class="w3-xlarge">'.$counter.'</td>
                <td class="w3-xlarge">'.$user.'</td>';
                $sql2 = "SELECT count(status) AS sales FROM vicidial_agent_log WHERE user = '$user' AND DATE(event_time) = CURDATE() AND status = 'SALE'";
                $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
                while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo
                    '<td class="w3-xlarge">'.$row2['sales'].'</td>';
                    $sql3 = "SELECT count(status) AS salesWeek FROM vicidial_agent_log WHERE user = '$user' AND WEEK(event_time) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(event_time) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND status = 'SALE'";
                    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
                    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        echo
                        '<td class="w3-xlarge">'.$row3['salesWeek'].'</td>';
                        $sql4 = "SELECT count(status) AS salesMonth FROM vicidial_agent_log WHERE user = '$user' AND MONTH(event_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(event_time) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND status = 'SALE'";
                        $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
                        while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            echo
                            '<td class="w3-xlarge">'.$row4['salesMonth'].'</td>
                            </tr>';
                            $counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

What I want is for the table to be sorted by highest monthly sales with the highest being at the top and lowest at the bottom.

I have done some research and the solutions I've found I could not get to work with this situation for example, a JS sort from W3Schools wouldn't work and I think this is due to the values being called from the database.

I hope this is clear, any advice on how to tackle this is appreciated :)

Comment: I think if you made one overall query to get this data, containing a series of subqueries for each figure, then you could use ORDER BY in the outer SQL to sort by the monthly sales column

Comment: Alternatively, if you tried something using JS and it didn't work for some reason, please show us your code and explain the problem, then we can fix it. The values having come from the server-side shouldn't really be a problem in itself.

Comment: I will try to get it all into one query, this is what I wanted to achieve initially I just need to learn how to do one query which spans across two different tables.